# sitecore: bind link of items

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemplaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </LayoutTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                           <sc:Image runat="server" ID="ImageRenderer1" Field="ThumbImage" 
                            Item="<%# Container.DataItem as Sitecore.Data.Items.Item %>" />     

                             <sc:FieldRenderer ID="FieldRenderer2" runat="server" FieldName="Headline" 
                            Item="<%# Container.DataItem as Sitecore.Data.Items.Item %>" /><br />
             </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
string path = "/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc";
var item = sc.Context.Database.GetItem(path);
MultilistField m = item.Fields["test"];
Item[] collection = m.GetItems();
ListView1.DataSource = dataset;
ListView1.DataBind();
```

In MultilistField, m, it will get at least 10 items. Now, I need to create the link for headline field where user will click on the link, it will redirect user to that particular item. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Sitecore **LinkManager** class to get the links like this:

```
<a href="<%# Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Container.DataItem as Sitecore.Data.Items.Item) %>">
    headline code here
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, never thought of it..~